# ARSceneView not available, does it have to be created manually?

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, sceneform

I am currently trying to place a 3D object in my AR Android app. The following line of code always results in an abort of the app and a NullpointerException.

I placed the Fragment and I can see the camera Image. Planes are also detected. Doesn't this show that the fragment has been implemented correctly?

```
FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
arFragment = (ArFragment) fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);
ArSceneView arSceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();
```

What can be the reasons why ARScenView is not created automatically? Can I create it myself?

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: I think I've already found the mistake. I wanted to use ARSceneView in a fragment. As soon as I use an activity instead, it works fine. Am I right?